# Are atomic swaps possible between Monero and other altcoins or Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, altcoin

Are atomic swaps possible between Monero and Bitcoin / altcoins? What features are needed to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like there could be a neat novel way to do it, according to [MimbleWimble mailing list post by A. Poelstra](https://lists.launchpad.net/mimblewimble/msg00086.html).

> Note that the s' values need to be re-communicated every time the transaction changes (as does the nonce). Because it depends on the other party's nonce, this might require an additional round of interaction per channel update.
>
> Note also that nothing I've said depends at all on what's being signed. This means this works just as well for MimbleWimble as it would for Bitcoin+Schnorr as it would for Monero (with a multisig ring-CT construction) as it would for Ethereum+Schnorr. Further, it can link transactions across chains.
>
> I'm very excited about this.
>
> Cheers
>
> Andrew

There's also some discussion about it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/60nq4u/andrew_poelstra_ethan_heilman_atomic_swaps_are/).